# Shortcut to paste text in command prompt

Tags: windows, command-line, keyboard-shortcuts, copy-paste, ms-dos

How can I paste a text in command prompt through shortcuts?  Normally if we press <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>v</kbd>, it won't paste text on Windows command prompt.

Is there any alternative shortcut or any way I can define a custom shortcut for pasting text in Windows' command prompt?

I already read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/131955/keyboard-shortcut-to-paste-clipboard-content-into-command-prompt-window-win-xp) and the answer requires me to install AutoHotkey, which I do not want. Are there any alternatives?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you dont want to use Auto Hotkey, You can use the Alt+Space keyboard combination to bring up the window menu, then hit the E key, and then the P key. This will trigger the menus and paste into the console.

Once you practice this regularly, this wont be much difficult but at start you will have some problems but this works